# Ruby On Rails: Confused on ActiveRecord has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here is a simple example illustrating my problem:

Say I have two models Car and Color, where Color has two attributes Name and HexValue.

I want Car to have one color but I don't want a 1-1 relationship between Car and Color.

How can I create an association that specifies this? I know that I can add a foreign key to Car that refers to a single entry in Color but I feel like this isn't an elegant way of doing this since you will have to join the two tables to get the color of the car. Is there anyway I can create a relationship where I can just do car1.color.name to get the name of the color?

Keep in mind that I don't want to create a 1-1 relationship and I only want a set amount of colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Car should `belong_to :color`, and color should `has_many :cars`.

Comment: As I clearly stated, I don't want a 1-1 relationship or a nested relationship. I was just using car1.color.name to show what I would want to be able to do. I'm not sure if it is even possible.

Comment: This solution isn't nested or 1:1, you might have commented on my typo. With this you can do some_car.color.name.

Comment: If you use this solution you will be able to call car.color.name

Comment: this confuses me, even though a car belongs to a color, you can use some_car.color? that's very interesting

Comment: Yeah, I see how it can be confusing. You can always go both ways in associated records, as long as you make the `has_many` and `belongs_to` declarations in your models.

Comment: One last question: How would I generate a form for Car that will allow me to choose the color in addition to all of Car's other fields? Would it be the same as if you were creating a nested form? I want to be able to set the id for the Color entry as the foreign key :color_id in Car.

Comment: The basic solution is `f.select(:color_id, Color.all)`, but you'll want to look into it more.